# mdadm - cant read superblock - can I zero the superblocks without erasing data and recreate a raid?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid, mdadm

Today I had to fix a Server Fan by disassembling and rebuild it. After booting the server I had the problem that all disks where not at the same location they have been yesterday. So the system couldnt mount my array. Now all disks have the old path as it was before... But my system is unable to mount them on boot, giving me the error "cant read superblock" I am not that familiar with raid configurations. Thats why I am always scared of running the wrong command and wiping all disks.

Thats why I am asking, is it safe to zero the superblocks and recreate a "new" raid5 array?

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
md127 : inactive sda[0](S) sdb[1](S) sdd[4](S) sdc[2](S)
      7813529952 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
```

I tried the following:

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127

# mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md/vo1, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md/vo1, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md/vo1, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md/vo1, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md/vo1 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md/vo1 as 1 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md/vo1 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md/vo1 as 2
mdadm: /dev/md/vo1 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

Details show me that it has set Raid0 instead of Raid5.

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 4

              Name : ncloud:vo1  (local to host ncloud)
              UUID : b8ecad1a:56e6c31c:35bb6532:3dd2f9c7
            Events : 5102

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       32        -        /dev/sdc
       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

There are 2 disks that have each 1 missing state.

**Edit #2**

```
root@ncloud:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcd]
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b8ecad1a:56e6c31c:35bb6532:3dd2f9c7
           Name : ncloud:vo1  (local to host ncloud)
  Creation Time : Wed Dec  9 13:01:02 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c0e60330:de836b95:5dd932a0:fe90c3dd

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug 23 00:45:53 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 96c1485f - correct
         Events : 5102

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b8ecad1a:56e6c31c:35bb6532:3dd2f9c7
           Name : ncloud:vo1  (local to host ncloud)
  Creation Time : Wed Dec  9 13:01:02 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 27b3f2cd:ca5d1594:625c4478:48e2a2d6

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug 23 00:45:53 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 44ac303 - correct
         Events : 5102

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b8ecad1a:56e6c31c:35bb6532:3dd2f9c7
           Name : ncloud:vo1  (local to host ncloud)
  Creation Time : Wed Dec  9 13:01:02 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5e2a55e9:81dce8d4:8e4f5dce:e270f7a5

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug 23 09:48:16 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 85efb9d6 - correct
         Events : 5102

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : b8ecad1a:56e6c31c:35bb6532:3dd2f9c7
           Name : ncloud:vo1  (local to host ncloud)
  Creation Time : Wed Dec  9 13:01:02 2020
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764976 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=176 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 22630b19:7930354b:7e3784a8:4f7396b7

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Aug 23 09:48:16 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 17b830f0 - correct
         Events : 5102

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

**EDIT #3**

```
OK root@ncloud:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
OK root@ncloud:~# mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md127 /dev/sd[abcd]
mdadm: /dev/md127 has been started with 4 drives.
OK root@ncloud:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sda[0] sdd[4] sdc[2] sdb[1]
      5860147200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

root@ncloud:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md127 
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Dec  9 13:01:02 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 5860147200 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Aug 23 00:45:53 2021
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 128K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : ncloud:vo1  (local to host ncloud)
              UUID : b8ecad1a:56e6c31c:35bb6532:3dd2f9c7
            Events : 5102

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        0        0      active sync   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       2       8       32        2      active sync   /dev/sdc
       4       8       48        3      active sync   /dev/sdd
```

**Edit 4**

After scaning details to mdadm.conf, uncommenting my line in fstab (UUID of array was the same), also update-initramfs -u  and rebooting. I saw the following in dmesg:

```
Error root@ncloud:~# dmesg | grep block
[   11.326178] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[   11.328529] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[   12.198036] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[   12.200996] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[  144.497538] EXT4-fs (md127): unable to read superblock

Personalities : 
md127 : inactive sdd[4](S) sdc[2](S) sda[0](S) sdb[1](S)
      7813529952 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
```

**EDIT 5 DMESG**

I just booted up the system and none of the HDD's came up. I always shut down systems when I go to bed.

```
[   44.331998] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[   44.332253] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   44.332262] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Mode Sense: 67 00 10 08
[   44.333022] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[   44.333748] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[   44.335655] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[   44.335907] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   44.335916] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 67 00 10 08
[   44.336385] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
[   44.337327] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[   44.574978] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 15
[   44.635129] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.635152] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[   44.635234] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.635253] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[   44.635322] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[   44.635366] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on
[   44.635386] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 5c 10 8b c4
[   44.636524] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.636544] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[   44.636625] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.636643] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[   44.636865] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   44.815456] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.815467] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   44.815500] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.815507] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   44.815535] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[   44.816034] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.816042] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   44.816075] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   44.816082] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   44.816132] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   46.625314] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   46.845292] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   47.064953] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 16, error -71
[   47.295335] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   47.515295] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   47.734964] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 17, error -71
[   47.743443] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[   48.505310] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   48.725233] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   48.944928] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 18, error -71
[   49.175256] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   49.395303] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[   49.614958] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 19, error -71
[   49.623420] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[   63.844995] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   64.054967] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   64.068262] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   64.685012] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   64.767524] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   65.365009] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[   65.755417] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   65.975280] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   66.194952] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 20, error -71
[   66.425315] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   66.645324] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   66.864943] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 21, error -71
[   66.873409] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[   67.645288] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   67.865275] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   68.084979] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 22, error -71
[   68.315282] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   68.535306] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[   68.754993] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 23, error -71
[   68.763463] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[  267.345137] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  267.565113] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  267.784800] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 24, error -71
[  268.895181] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  269.115322] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  269.334860] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 25, error -71
[  269.335263] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  270.545312] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  270.765244] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  270.984922] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 26, error -71
[  271.215265] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  271.435271] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  271.654947] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 27, error -71
[  271.655343] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[  272.085001] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  273.145469] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  273.365365] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  273.585013] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 28, error -71
[  273.815367] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  274.035413] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  274.255037] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 29, error -71
[  274.263447] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  275.025412] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  275.245477] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  275.465093] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 30, error -71
[  275.695434] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  275.915439] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  276.135142] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 31, error -71
[  276.143608] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[  277.225494] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  277.445492] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  277.665166] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 32, error -71
[  278.705210] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  279.875710] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  280.095620] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  280.315260] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 34, error -71
[  280.545634] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  280.765611] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  280.985280] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 35, error -71
[  280.993740] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[  281.755646] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  281.975646] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  282.195368] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 36, error -71
[  282.425667] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  282.645665] usb 2-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[  282.865366] usb 2-1: device not accepting address 37, error -71
[  282.873826] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[  283.105694] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  283.325685] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  283.545360] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 38, error -71
[  283.775712] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  283.995714] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  284.215384] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 39, error -71
[  284.223859] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  284.985762] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  285.205835] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  285.425431] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 40, error -71
[  285.655770] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  285.875801] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[  286.095503] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 41, error -71
[  286.103979] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

**EDIT 6**

For me dmesg's errors seemed like my pi suffers from power. I have an Allnet NAS with a Rock-Pi SATA head. It will be powered by a 45W power supply via USB-C. The HDD's itself are connected via SATA and GPIO Ports on the Raspberry, but the HDD's are additionally connected via USB3<->USB3 port connection from the PI4 board to Rock-Pi SATA port.
I unplugged this. Booted the system and after booting adding the USB3 Ports back. After this dmesg is silent about read errors. IT seems fine as nothing has happened... really strange.

Comment: could you post output for `--examine` of all drives with the fields for `Raid Level` `Update Time` `Checksum` and `Events`

Zero superblock is only safe if you intent to lose data.

Comment: If you can find 3 drives with the same Event count you are probably safe to assamble them, watch the order, and use missing for any drive if needed
But do investigate why the drives are missing, you mention raspberry, make sure connections are good, check dmesg for explanations why drives go away, and check powersupply.

New drives does not automatically mean "error free", and it is also for disk copy to do tests without "risking data"

Comment: I've taken my NAS apart and plugged a usb SATA drive to see if these drives are still working. It seems that they can be recognized by my notebook, but my RPI4 seems to have trouble with these. Is these a way to erase cache or something? So that the pie behaves as it would see the drives for the first time? Dmesg is silent about the other 2 drives. It only mentions the first 2.

Comment: examing disks worked now without a problem and pretty fast. I updated my post again.
I would be happy if you could take a short look if thats ok?!

Comment: They disagree on state, but Event is same on all of them, updated answer.

Comment: Assemble, and then check the filesystem, not sure why you try to restart things.
The superblock is the ext4 superblock on the device, you need to read more context in dmesg.

Comment: I updated my post with dmesg. Seems that there are some read errors...

Answer (score 0):

There is a almost identical issue and post at https://superuser.com/a/811116/250231

Verify which drives to use before starting, either all of them, or one missing to later rebuild.
In the end start with `--assemble --force` important that the order is correct.

Based on latest `--examine` data you should be good with:

```sh
mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md127 /dev/sd[abcd]
cat /proc/mdstat
```

`a` and `b` was probably disconnected first, and that information was updated on `c` and `d`, so that is why you got this issue.
Again I can not stress enough that you should try to understand why they where disconnected, `dmesg` and logs shows this, get that data if drives is disconnected - before restarting. (It could be flaky power supply or connectors.)

Only zero superblock if you are ready to lose data.

Comment: Well... I listened on someone else who told me to modprobe raid456 and now everything seems gone. no more disks attached. No more array information available.. I right now have no Idea on where to start.

Comment: @G4nja so you are saying that your disks are gone and `--examine` on the disk as you did before shows nothing? Please dump dmesg to a safe place for possible future use, then try to figure out what happened, maybe your disks are actually bad and was disconnected, run `smartctl -a /dev/sd...` on them if you do find them.

Comment: Dont know what to do... I had 4 HDD's now 2 are gone. not visible via blkid or fdisk -l ... its such a nightmare.. dont know if I can use these disks again or recover somehow
On my raspberry I cant find smartctl.

Comment: Short update ... after 4th reboot.. the HDD's are back. I try now to gather as much information as I can and try to assemble --force asap

Comment: @G4nja first, calm down! Do you not have backups? look at dmesg! do not restart the machine. DO NOT assemble until you know what is bad and where. If you do not have backup YOU ARE RISKING DATA. Read carefully before doing anything!

Comment: First of, thanks for helping. I checked dmesg, but there is no visible error or fail. I commented out the lines in fstab and mdadm.conf. That did the trick for the disks to come back. Should I try to assemble --force now? BTW, this is somehow my "backup" I try to move from onedrive to nextcloud

Comment: Please update your post with the missing examine, redo it for all disks and update your post with current state.

Comment: I updated. I think I somehow f*ckd up

Comment: Is there a way I can access 1 HDD, rescue some data and wipe every disk? It seems like the disks come and go without any reason. I rebooted and now I only see /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

Comment: RAID 5, you must have at least n-1 drives to be able to get data.
Get new drives and copy all data over and then work from the copy.

Comment: Thank you, I update my post to show you the results.
Should I brief scan it to the mdadm.conf and update fstab?
The reason I had this issue, was due to my own stupidity. I fixed the server fan and rebooted the system without having drives attached. This led to being drives located at a wrong position and in my panic I tried multiple things to get everything back to normal. So i dont think this was an issue due to hardware issue.

Comment: It seems that I am almost back to where I started... I have again the problem that the superblock cannot be red. See my latest update.

Comment: i belive, due the raid ZERO and the DMESG that a drive seems to be gone to hell and you need to restore from backup, however i would run a fs-check on that filesystem maybe its only corrupt

Answer (score 0):

After having all disks back in a normal state I assembled and checked dmesg. How shall I proceed from here?

```
[  637.106944] md: md127 stopped.
[  639.456955] md: md127 stopped.
[  639.674450] raid6: neonx8   gen()  2838 MB/s
[  639.844453] raid6: neonx8   xor()  2332 MB/s
[  640.014457] raid6: neonx4   gen()  3976 MB/s
[  640.184458] raid6: neonx4   xor()  2457 MB/s
[  640.354461] raid6: neonx2   gen()  3801 MB/s
[  640.524464] raid6: neonx2   xor()  2767 MB/s
[  640.694468] raid6: neonx1   gen()  2919 MB/s
[  640.864470] raid6: neonx1   xor()  2377 MB/s
[  641.034474] raid6: int32x8  gen()   953 MB/s
[  641.204484] raid6: int32x8  xor()   562 MB/s
[  641.374493] raid6: int32x4  gen()   959 MB/s
[  641.544499] raid6: int32x4  xor()   652 MB/s
[  641.714492] raid6: int32x2  gen()  1047 MB/s
[  641.884488] raid6: int32x2  xor()   587 MB/s
[  642.054510] raid6: int32x1  gen()   951 MB/s
[  642.224503] raid6: int32x1  xor()   485 MB/s
[  642.224510] raid6: using algorithm neonx4 gen() 3976 MB/s
[  642.224516] raid6: .... xor() 2457 MB/s, rmw enabled
[  642.224523] raid6: using neon recovery algorithm
[  642.232248] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[  642.234908]    arm4regs        :  3775 MB/sec
[  642.238331]    8regs           :  2877 MB/sec
[  642.241769]    32regs          :  2865 MB/sec
[  642.243454]    neon            :  5860 MB/sec
[  642.243460] xor: using function: neon (5860 MB/sec)
[  642.246566] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[  642.265239] md/raid:md127: device sdc operational as raid disk 0
[  642.265250] md/raid:md127: device sdb operational as raid disk 3
[  642.265257] md/raid:md127: device sda operational as raid disk 2
[  642.265263] md/raid:md127: device sdd operational as raid disk 1
[  642.268157] md/raid:md127: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[  642.290815] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 6000790732800
[  643.066768] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 data cmplt err -75 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[  643.066788] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#3 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 e8 e0 87 78 00 00 80 00

OK root@ncloud:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdc[0] sdb[4] sda[2] sdd[1]
      5860147200 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Well... I think my device is giving up somehow:

```
[ 1261.323761] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARNING: Host System Error
[ 1261.355783] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
[ 1266.335275] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 1266.335291] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: USBSTS: HSE EINT
[ 1266.367308] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
[ 1266.367318] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[ 1266.367375] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[ 1266.367432] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 1266.367442] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: USBSTS: HSE EINT
[ 1266.399457] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host halt failed, -110
[ 1266.399525] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1266.400418] usb 2-1: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1266.400441] usb 2-1: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1266.400460] usb 2-1: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1266.400555] usb 2-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1266.400574] usb 2-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1266.400592] usb 2-2: cmd cmplt err -108
[ 1266.401506] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 1266.401952] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#8 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[ 1266.401968] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1266.401987] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[ 1266.401998] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1266.402035] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#8 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00 cmd_age=35s
[ 1266.402056] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#8 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1266.402088] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1266.402104] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1266.402121] md/raid:md127: Disk failure on sdb, disabling device.
               md/raid:md127: Operation continuing on 3 devices.
[ 1266.403346] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00 cmd_age=35s
[ 1266.403368] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#10 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1266.403396] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1266.403406] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1266.403465] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1266.403474] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1266.404016] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1266.445374] scsi host0: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED to get lock err -19
[ 1266.445396] sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1266.445412] sd 0:0:0:1: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1266.445426] sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1266.445439] sd 0:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1266.445500] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#9 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x06 cmd_age=39s
[ 1266.445518] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] tag#9 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 08 ce c2 00 00 00 78 00
[ 1266.445538] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 147767808 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 15 prio class 0
[ 1266.445557] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767808 on sdb).
[ 1266.445576] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767816 on sdb).
[ 1266.445591] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767824 on sdb).
[ 1266.445607] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767832 on sdb).
[ 1266.445621] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767840 on sdb).
[ 1266.445636] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767848 on sdb).
[ 1266.445651] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767856 on sdb).
[ 1266.445665] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767864 on sdb).
[ 1266.445680] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767872 on sdb).
[ 1266.445695] md/raid:md127: read error not correctable (sector 147767880 on sdb).
[ 1266.495304] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1138330192 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x3000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1266.495337] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 147766592 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 24 prio class 0
[ 1266.495378] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1953499288 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
[ 1267.005311] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1267.088166] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1267.695405] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1267.736689] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x82, streams are being disabled already
[ 1267.740901] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1267.741459] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 1267.741479] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1267.741502] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] tag#3 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[ 1267.741517] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] tag#3 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1267.741545] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00 cmd_age=36s
[ 1267.741598] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#2 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1267.741642] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1267.741656] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.741764] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1267.741777] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.741846] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] tag#3 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00 cmd_age=36s
[ 1267.741868] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] tag#3 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[ 1267.741896] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 16 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x20800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1267.741908] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.742000] scsi host1: uas_eh_device_reset_handler FAILED to get lock err -19
[ 1267.742024] sd 1:0:0:1: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1267.742062] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] tag#4 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x06 cmd_age=36s
[ 1267.742084] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] tag#4 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 74 70 08 98 00 00 28 00
[ 1267.742166] sd 1:0:0:1: rejecting I/O to offline device
[ 1267.742185] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.742283] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.742353] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.742382] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.757485] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1267.806312] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.806373] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.825329] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.825431] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.825456] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.825510] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.855320] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.855592] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.855637] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.885335] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.885475] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.885510] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.885571] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.905381] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.905906] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.905969] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.925341] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.925477] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.925511] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.925569] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.945376] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.945742] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.945805] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.975338] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.975477] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.975512] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.975572] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.995380] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.995742] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1267.995806] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015354] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015490] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015544] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015580] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015638] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015891] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.015953] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.035346] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.035483] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.035518] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.035575] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.055344] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.055492] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.055555] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.085342] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.085479] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.085544] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.085623] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.115336] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.115611] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #53346523: comm php: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1268.115747] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.115812] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135385] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135514] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135552] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135615] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1268.135620] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135645] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135780] scsi 1:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
[ 1268.135799] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135854] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135919] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.135975] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136010] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136068] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136152] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136352] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136383] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136451] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136520] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136557] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136590] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136647] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136770] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136801] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.136860] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.137806] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.137838] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.137900] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.137963] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.137998] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138029] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138085] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138350] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138381] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138440] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138504] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138539] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138569] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138625] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138801] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138832] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138889] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138952] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.138988] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139018] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139074] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139317] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139349] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139407] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139473] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139508] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139538] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139594] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139771] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139803] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139860] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139923] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139958] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.139988] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140047] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140217] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140248] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140308] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140371] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140406] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140436] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140492] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140658] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140689] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140744] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140806] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140841] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140871] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.140929] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141094] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141126] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141181] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141243] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141301] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141358] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141443] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141648] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141708] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141792] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141844] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141903] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.141962] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142048] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142251] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142311] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142395] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142448] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142505] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142563] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142644] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142878] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.142937] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143019] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143070] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143128] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143186] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143270] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143430] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143489] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143569] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143620] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143678] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143736] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143818] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.143929] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.143977] EXT4-fs (md127): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1268.144063] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144124] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144206] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144258] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144318] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144375] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144457] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144631] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144662] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144717] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144777] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144835] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144892] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.144976] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.145162] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #53346523: comm php: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1268.145616] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.145683] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.145774] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.145832] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.145891] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.145975] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146049] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146551] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146614] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146703] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146759] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146817] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146873] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.146953] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147204] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147264] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147352] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147405] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147462] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147520] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147603] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147805] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147865] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.147949] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148001] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148059] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148117] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148199] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148391] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148451] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148539] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148590] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148648] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148706] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.148789] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149111] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149171] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149257] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149309] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149368] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149447] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149523] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.149729] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): ext4_end_bio:349: I/O error 10 writing to inode 53280868 starting block 55313728)
[ 1268.149823] EXT4-fs error (device md127): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:216: comm kworker/u8:0: Error while async write back metadata
[ 1268.149912] Aborting journal on device md127-8.
[ 1268.151388] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.151441] EXT4-fs (md127): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1268.151450] EXT4-fs (md127): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 1268.151684] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #53346523: comm php: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1268.151780] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.151822] EXT4-fs (md127): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1268.151827] EXT4-fs (md127): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 1268.151845] EXT4-fs error (device md127) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:5751: Journal has aborted
[ 1268.151969] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152040] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152147] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152207] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152267] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152327] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152413] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.152532] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 732463104, lost sync page write
[ 1268.152577] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for md127-8.
[ 1268.152607] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.152651] EXT4-fs (md127): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1268.152656] EXT4-fs (md127): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 1268.152834] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #53346523: comm php: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1268.152924] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.152966] EXT4-fs (md127): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1268.152971] EXT4-fs (md127): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 1268.152989] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_ext_dirty:169: inode #53280868: comm kworker/u8:0: mark_inode_dirty error
[ 1268.153049] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.153093] EXT4-fs (md127): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1268.153251] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #53346523: comm php: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1268.153333] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.153447] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.153501] EXT4-fs warning (device md127): ext4_convert_unwritten_extents:4773: inode #53280868: block 0: len 463: ext4_ext_map_blocks returned -30
[ 1268.153525] EXT4-fs error (device md127): ext4_check_bdev_write_error:216: comm kworker/u8:0: Error while async write back metadata
[ 1268.153632] EXT4-fs error (device md127): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #53346523: comm php: reading directory lblock 0
[ 1268.153722] Buffer I/O error on dev md127, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1268.155451] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313408
[ 1268.155484] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313409
[ 1268.155508] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313410
[ 1268.155531] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313411
[ 1268.155553] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313412
[ 1268.155577] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313413
[ 1268.155601] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313414
[ 1268.155625] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313415
[ 1268.155648] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313416
[ 1268.155671] Buffer I/O error on device md127, logical block 55313417
[ 1268.161394] EXT4-fs error (device md127): ext4_journal_check_start:83: Detected aborted journal
[ 1268.316504] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 1268.595348] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.595373] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.615340] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.615393] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.615414] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.635347] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1268.875381] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=0x00
[ 1268.945945] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x82, streams are being disabled already
[ 1271.380943] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1271.380967] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1271.380983] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1272.988813] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1272.988857] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1272.988891] md: super_written gets error=-5
[ 1272.990814] md127: detected capacity change from 6000790732800 to 0
[ 1272.990894] md: md127 stopped.
```

Comment: read the log, sda and sdb has issues, sdb even has bad blocks, you should replace those drives.

Comment: I managed to backup everything whats necessary. After booting, all Disks are up and running for about an hour, then some errors occur. Do you think it would help to wipe everything and build a new raid with new blocks? Should I just zero the superblocks?

Comment: If you read the dmesg log you will see that your disk have bad blocks, replace them.